# Deploying Laravel App ( with Scheduler ) on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and running the schedule

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have recently built a mobile app in React-Native along with its associated backend Laravel application / SQL database. The app and database have been tested on a locally hosted server and I am ready to deploy.
I deployed the application and database to AWS Elastic Beanstalk following the tutorial

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html

The app was deployed successfully and I set up the DB as well in the Elastic Beanstalk Console.

The only problem was to run the schedule.

I have no idea of how to do it!

I tried to create a cron job following the

> https://medium.com/@joelennon/running-cron-jobs-on-amazon-web-services-aws-elastic-beanstalk-a41d91d1c571

I created a cron.yaml file at the root of my project, like this.

```
version: 1
cron:
 — name: "schedule"
   url: "/schedule"
   schedule: "0 */12 * * *"
```

And then I deployed it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

> The configuration file cron.yaml in application version 69degrees-16
>   contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: while
>   parsing a block mapping in "", line 3, column 2: — name:
>   "schedule" ^ expected , but found BlockMappingStart in
>   "", line 4, column 4: url: "/schedule" ^ , JSON exception:
>   Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (v) at position 0.. Update the
>   configuration file.

In a word, what I want is to run the schedule on AWS. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and I came across your subject empty of answer.
Finally, I found the solution! You need replace the character ([em dash](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%E2%80%94)) `—` by ([hyphen-minus](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=-)) `-`. The difference is small but that's what corrected my mistake.